# SAS: Change time series freuqncy (Proc Expand)

Tags: sas, time-series, expand

I have a stock price dataset which has observations in miliseconds (Variables: STOCK DATE TIME(in ms) PRICE. It is sorted by stock, date, and time.

I now need a dataset where the freuqency is 1-second intervals. The price variable should be the prevailing price at the second.

I tried proc expand:

```
proc expand data=have out=want to=second; 
id stock date time; run;
```

But it does not work that way.
Any help is appreciated!

M

Comment: got it: proc timeseries with id time and interval=second works!

Answer (score 0):

got it: proc timeseries with id time and interval=second works!